# How to skip DNSBL checks for authenticated main in Exim4

Tags: linux, exim, rbl

I have the following ACL with Exim4:

```
acl_check_rcpt:
    deny message  = DNSRBL Access denied - $sender_host_address \ 
                    listed by $dnslist_domain\n$dnslist_text 
         dnslists = zen.spamhaus.org : b.barracudacentral.org
```

This applies the DNSBL to all mail, but I'd like to add an exception to only check incoming mail (or to skip the checks for mail delivered via an  SMTP-authenticated session).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems easiest to me to just juggle the order of the tests in acl_check_rcpt such that something like the following is above the DNSBL test you're having trouble with:

```
accept  authenticated = *
```

So, rather than adding an exception to the DNSBL check, you simply accept the mail before you ever get to the DNSBL check if the sender is authenticated.